# pod lib lint fails with circular dependency even with newer fixed podspec available

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I've two private pods: `Services` and `AppUI`. With the new Cocoapods 0.35 release the `Service` pod broke because I was using circular dependencies, since to fix it I made breaking changes and released it as `v2.0-alpha.1`.

`AppUI` has a subspec called `Presenters` that depend on `Services/Models`:

```
s.subspec 'Presenters' do |presenters|
  presenters.source_files = 'Classes/Presenters/**/*.{h,m}'

  presenters.dependency 'AppUI/Core'
  presenters.dependency 'Services/Models'
end
```

When I try to run `pod lib lint` on it it fails with this error:

> [!] There is a circular dependency between Services/Directors and Services/Models

Which is exactly the problem fixed by version `2.0-alpha.1`. Running `pod lib lint --verbose` I found this:

```
Creating possibility state for Services/Models (4 remaining)
  Attempting to activate Services/Models (2.0-alpha.1)
  Unsatisfied by requested spec
  Unwinding for conflict: Services/Models
Creating possibility state for Services/Models (3 remaining)
  Attempting to activate Services/Models (1.0)
```

It first tries the correct version but falls back to the old `1.0` because of a cryptic "Unsatisfied by requested spec". The requested spec doesn't specify version how is it unsatisfied? I can't specify `'~> 2'` because the `AppUI` supports fine the old as well as the new release.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CocoaPods 0.35, by default pre-releases (ie, 2.0-alpha.1) will be excluded unless you explicitly ask for them.

You can use the following to explicitly resolve that version:

```
pod 'Services', '2.0-alpha.1'
```

Or, something like this to get the latest version, pre-release or not:

```
pod 'Services', '> 0.0.0.pre'
```